# Error when implementing onMarkupSelectedBinded this.markup event is null MarkupsCore

Tags: autodesk-forge

How can I use the onMarkupSelected event in MarkupsCore, and when implementing the onMarkupSelectedBinded event Markup.js returns an error stating that this.markup is null.

```
var _markup;
ExtesionsOpenMarkup.prototype.createUi = function (event) {
    _viewer = this.viewer;
    setViewableData()
    _btnMarkup = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button('btn-markup');
    _btnMarkup.onClick = function (e) {
        _markup = _viewer.getExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore");
        createToolBarMarkup();
        _markup.onMarkupSelectedBinded = function () {
            alert('test')
        }
    };    
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

The Markup extension exposes an [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) interface you can use to subscribe to its events. Try the following snippet of code in your button click handler:

```
const markupExtension = _viewer.getExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore");
const namespace = Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core;
markupExtension.addEventListener(namespace.EVENT_MARKUP_SELECTED, function(ev) {
    console.log(ev.markup);
    alert('Markup selected!');
});
```

Comment: Glad to hear that :) Cheers!